# How do you configure Elmah to tweet error messages?

Tags: elmah

I read that Elmah can tweet error messages so I tried to set it up, but could not get it to work.  I am able to get it to save the errors into a database and email me the error, but the tweet doesn't seem to work.

Here is my configuration:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="elmah">
        <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah"/>
        <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
        <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
        <section name="errorTweet" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorTweetSectionHandler, Elmah"/>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<elmah>
    <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
    <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlServerCompactErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="LoggingDB" />
    <errorTweet 
        userName="twitter_username" 
        password="twitter_password" statusFormat="{Message}" />
</elmah>

<system.webServer>
    <modules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ErrorTweet" type="Elmah.ErrorTweetModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

No errors occur, the tweet just does not appear even though it's logged in the database and emailed.

Answer (score 0):

See the [ErrorHowling](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/wiki/HowlingErrors) wiki on the [project's site](http://elmah.googlecode.com/) for some background and information on `ErrorTweetModule` and its use.